# Distribute invoice amounts into columns based on a separate value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Setup:
I'm trying to make a statement, where invoice amounts are dropped into columns based on their age. Id also like each column to have a total at the bottom.

Right now, I dump the data into Excel and manipulate with index(match) and an if statement. It's ugly and open to human error.

I'm trying to look at the DaysDue field of my raw data, and distribute the InvBlance into the appropriate columns as below.
sample data:

```
invoice: 1 daysdue:85 Invbalance: 8500.00  
invoice: 2 daysdue:35 Invbalance: 3500.00  
invoice: 3 daysdue:15 Invbalance: 1500.00  
invoice: 4 daysdue:10 Invbalance: 1000.00
```

```
Invoice# | current (less than 30 | 31-60 days | 61-90 days | 91+    |     Total
1        |                       |            |   8500.00  |        |   8500.00
2        |                       |    3500.00 |            |        |   3500.00
3        |        1500.00        |            |            |        |   1500.00
4        |        1000.00        |            |            |        |   1000.00
Total    |        2500.00        |    3500.00 |   8500.00  | sum    |  14500.00
```

This is my code so far. Also this is a live database.

```
SELECT  
    RTS_ARByInvoiceCustomerInfo.InvoiceNumber AS 'Invoice#',  
    RTS_ARByInvoiceCustomerInfo.DaysFromDueDate AS 'DaysDue',  
    RTS_ARByInvoiceCustomerInfo.AmountRemaining AS 'InvBalance' 
FROM
    TrulinXLive.dbo.RTS_ARByInvoiceCustomerInfo RTS_ARByInvoiceCustomerInfo 
ORDER BY 
    RTS_ARByInvoiceCustomerInfo.InvoiceNumber
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not to be *that guy,* but have you considered writing a short py/js/whatever script that downloads the data and converts it to a csv? Then you can do pretty much whatever you want and have the benefit of a "real" programming language, with all the extensibility it provides. You can also give it read only access and avoid potentially breaking the db. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Your query isn't actually valid, has a floating comma. You can use a case expression per column for what you want.

Comment: This is actually not `"distribute"` but displaying the amount under different column. Use [case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) expression to do it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. I created a table variable with your sample data:

```sql
DECLARE @Data TABLE
(
    [InvoiceID] INT            NOT NULL,
    [DaysDue]   INT            NOT NULL,
    [Balance]   DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Data
(
    [InvoiceID],
    [DaysDue],
    [Balance]
)
VALUES
(1, 85, 8500.00),
(2, 35, 3500.00),
(3, 15, 1500.00),
(4, 10, 1000.00);

;WITH [transformed]
AS (SELECT CAST([InvoiceID] AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [Invoice #],
           CASE WHEN [DaysDue] BETWEEN 0 AND 29 THEN
                    [Balance]
                ELSE
                    NULL
           END AS [Current (less than 30)],
           CASE WHEN [DaysDue] BETWEEN 30 AND 60 THEN
                    [Balance]
                ELSE
                    NULL
           END AS [31-60 days],
           CASE WHEN [DaysDue] BETWEEN 61 AND 90 THEN
                    [Balance]
                ELSE
                    NULL
           END AS [61-90 days],
           CASE WHEN [DaysDue] > 90 THEN
                    [Balance]
                ELSE
                    NULL
           END AS [91+],
           [Balance] AS [Total]
    FROM   @Data)
SELECT [transformed].[Invoice #],
       [transformed].[Current (less than 30)],
       [transformed].[31-60 days],
       [transformed].[61-90 days],
       [transformed].[91+],
       [transformed].[Total]
FROM   [transformed]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total',
       SUM([transformed].[Current (less than 30)]),
       SUM([transformed].[31-60 days]),
       SUM([transformed].[61-90 days]),
       SUM([transformed].[91+]),
       SUM([transformed].[Total])
FROM   [transformed];
```

The output is:

| Invoice # | Current (less than 30) | 31-60 days | 61-90 days | 91+ | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | 8500.00 | NULL | 8500.00 |
| 2 | NULL | 3500.00 | NULL | NULL | 3500.00 |
| 3 | 1500.00 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1500.00 |
| 4 | 1000.00 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1000.00 |
| Total | 2500.00 | 3500.00 | 8500.00 | NULL | 14500.00 |

You can adjust for your actual table name, etc.